# Catch Inserted ID from Trigger

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, triggers

i'm new at SQL so, don't yell me. I have a problem with a trigger which is meant to catch last inserted data and update it.

```
create trigger ilgKodIsim on URTFIS instead of insert
as
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET IDENTITY_INSERT URTFIS ON

declare @id int;
insert into URTFIS ( [ID], [FISNO], [FISTAR], [URTTAR], [STATUS], [STOKID], [DEPOID], [BIRIMID], [MIKTAR],
[BIRIM1KATSAYI], [BIRIM2KATSAYI], [BIRIM3KATSAYI], [FIREORAN], [SIPARISID], [PROJEID], [KUR_RAPOR], 
[GENELTOPLAM], [GENELTOPLAM_RAPOR], [OZELGRUP1], [OZELGRUP2], [OZELALAN1], [OZELALAN2], [OZELALAN3], [OZELALAN4], [OZELALAN5], 
[OZELALAN6], [OZELALAN7], [OZELALAN8], [OZELALAN9], [OZELALAN10], [OZELALAN11], [OZELALAN12], [OZELALAN13],
[OZELALAN14], [OZELALAN15], [OZELALAN16], [OZELALAN17], [OZELALAN18], [OZELALAN19], [OZELALAN20], 
[ACIKLAMA], [BARKODID], [FATFISID], [MUHFISID], [SUBEID], [YETKIKODID], [OWN_URTFISID], [MASTER_URTFISID], 
[OTOMATIK_ALT_URUN], [GENELGRUP1], [GENELGRUP2], [GENELGRUP3], [GENELGRUP4], [GENELGRUP5], [ERP_LOTID], 
[ERP_LOT_CIKIS_GIRIS_HARID], [ERP_VARYANTID], [STKFISID], [STKFISHARID])

select

[ID], [FISNO], [FISTAR], [URTTAR], [STATUS], [STOKID], [DEPOID], [BIRIMID], [MIKTAR],
[BIRIM1KATSAYI], [BIRIM2KATSAYI], [BIRIM3KATSAYI], [FIREORAN], [SIPARISID], [PROJEID], [KUR_RAPOR], 
[GENELTOPLAM], [GENELTOPLAM_RAPOR], [OZELGRUP1], [OZELGRUP2],[OZELALAN1], [OZELALAN2], [OZELALAN3], [OZELALAN4], [OZELALAN5], 
[OZELALAN6], [OZELALAN7], [OZELALAN8], [OZELALAN9], [OZELALAN10], [OZELALAN11], [OZELALAN12], [OZELALAN13],
[OZELALAN14], [OZELALAN15], [OZELALAN16], [OZELALAN17], [OZELALAN18], [OZELALAN19], [OZELALAN20], 
[ACIKLAMA], [BARKODID], [FATFISID], [MUHFISID], [SUBEID], [YETKIKODID], [OWN_URTFISID], [MASTER_URTFISID], 
[OTOMATIK_ALT_URUN], [GENELGRUP1], [GENELGRUP2], [GENELGRUP3], [GENELGRUP4], [GENELGRUP5], [ERP_LOTID], 
[ERP_LOT_CIKIS_GIRIS_HARID], [ERP_VARYANTID], [STKFISID], [STKFISHARID]

from inserted

SET @id = Scope_Identity()

update URTFIS set OZELALAN2 = 'Deneme' where ID = @id

SET IDENTITY_INSERT URTFIS OFF
```

After I checked, values did not updated. And I can not figure it out.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: Why on earth would you do this - since you've taken over responsibility for inserting the data into the base table, there's no need to `INSERT` and then `UPDATE` the newly inserted row(s) (And note, *rows*, so that scalar variable's not going to work for multi-row inserted), just change `OZELALAN2` in the `SELECT` clause to be `'Deneme'` instead.

Comment: Actually, there is a software working. When user add some data in the table. i need some adjustments to this table.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `IDENTITY_INSERT`, you don't get a new identity value for `URTFIS.ID`.

Simply use the `ID` from `inserted`.

```
update URTFIS set OZELALAN2 = 'Deneme' where ID = SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Inserted
```

Or don't insert ID explicitly:

```
create trigger ilgKodIsim on URTFIS instead of insert
as
SET NOCOUNT ON


declare @id int;
insert into URTFIS ([FISNO], [FISTAR], [URTTAR], [STATUS], [STOKID],    [DEPOID], [BIRIMID], [MIKTAR],
[BIRIM1KATSAYI], [BIRIM2KATSAYI], [BIRIM3KATSAYI], [FIREORAN], [SIPARISID], [PROJEID], [KUR_RAPOR], 
[GENELTOPLAM], [GENELTOPLAM_RAPOR], [OZELGRUP1], [OZELGRUP2], [OZELALAN1], [OZELALAN2], [OZELALAN3], [OZELALAN4], [OZELALAN5], 
[OZELALAN6], [OZELALAN7], [OZELALAN8], [OZELALAN9], [OZELALAN10],     [OZELALAN11], [OZELALAN12], [OZELALAN13],
[OZELALAN14], [OZELALAN15], [OZELALAN16], [OZELALAN17], [OZELALAN18],     [OZELALAN19], [OZELALAN20], 
[ACIKLAMA], [BARKODID], [FATFISID], [MUHFISID], [SUBEID], [YETKIKODID], [OWN_URTFISID], [MASTER_URTFISID], 
[OTOMATIK_ALT_URUN], [GENELGRUP1], [GENELGRUP2], [GENELGRUP3], [GENELGRUP4], [GENELGRUP5], [ERP_LOTID], 
[ERP_LOT_CIKIS_GIRIS_HARID], [ERP_VARYANTID], [STKFISID], [STKFISHARID])

select

[FISNO], [FISTAR], [URTTAR], [STATUS], [STOKID], [DEPOID], [BIRIMID], [MIKTAR],
[BIRIM1KATSAYI], [BIRIM2KATSAYI], [BIRIM3KATSAYI], [FIREORAN], [SIPARISID], [PROJEID], [KUR_RAPOR], 
[GENELTOPLAM], [GENELTOPLAM_RAPOR], [OZELGRUP1], [OZELGRUP2],[OZELALAN1], [OZELALAN2], [OZELALAN3], [OZELALAN4], [OZELALAN5], 
[OZELALAN6], [OZELALAN7], [OZELALAN8], [OZELALAN9], [OZELALAN10], [OZELALAN11], [OZELALAN12], [OZELALAN13],
[OZELALAN14], [OZELALAN15], [OZELALAN16], [OZELALAN17], [OZELALAN18], [OZELALAN19], [OZELALAN20], 
[ACIKLAMA], [BARKODID], [FATFISID], [MUHFISID], [SUBEID], [YETKIKODID], [OWN_URTFISID], [MASTER_URTFISID], 
[OTOMATIK_ALT_URUN], [GENELGRUP1], [GENELGRUP2], [GENELGRUP3], [GENELGRUP4],     [GENELGRUP5], [ERP_LOTID], 
[ERP_LOT_CIKIS_GIRIS_HARID], [ERP_VARYANTID], [STKFISID], [STKFISHARID]

from inserted

SET @id = Scope_Identity()

update URTFIS set OZELALAN2 = 'Deneme' where ID = @id
```

Comment: İ tried but i got this error;

ClassName: EDatabaseError
Message :Update failed. Found 0 records.

i cant understand this error as well. It should  has some data. 
Thanks though.

Comment: Then try with other solution in my answer.

Comment: I tried. Once again i got same error. I can not catch the last inserted ID. I tried with after trigger but i failed. I search many entries bu i can not fix the problem. I search other possible errors but for now i detect nothing.

Comment: What about @@IDENTITY?

Comment: Why don't use set OZELALAN2  to 'Deneme'  in insert statement?

Comment: i can manage to solve this problem with Damien_The_Unbeliever's way. Thanks for your help and time friend.

Answer (score 1):

I would *guess* that what you need is actually more along the lines of:

```
create trigger ilgKodIsim on URTFIS
after insert --not instead of
as
SET NOCOUNT ON

update URTFIS set OZELALAN2 = 'Deneme' where ID IN (select ID from inserted)
```

I can see no reason to write an `instead of` trigger in which the first action is to perform exactly the same insert as would have happened had there been no trigger.

Trying to put "the" value of the inserted identity column into a scalar variable is doomed to fail since it's possible to write multi-row `INSERT` statements (indeed, there's an example of one in your original trigger). The trigger fires only once, there are *multiple* rows in `inserted` and so *multiple* identity values have just been assigned.